# Center scale animation css3

Tags: html, css, animation

How can I apply center to this scale animation?
As you see in next example the div dissapear to the right, I need to apply center to the scale animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".container:first").addClass("remove")
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .back p {
  margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.remove{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    -moz-transform-origin: right center;
    -o-transform-origin: right center;
    transform-origin: right center;
    animation: removeAnim 0.5s ease,
    otherAnimation 0.5s ease;
}
@keyframes otherAnimation {
    0%   {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    25%  {
        transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    50%  {
        transform: scale(0.50);
    }
    75%  {
        transform: scale(0.25);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="main"><br>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p>MyBack</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button>Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your .remove class in your CSS to:

```
transform-origin: center;
```

Or just remove all references to transform-origin in this class as the default is center anyway.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".container:first").addClass("remove")
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .back p {
  margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.remove{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    -moz-transform-origin: center;
    -o-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    animation: removeAnim 0.5s ease,
    otherAnimation 0.5s ease;
}
@keyframes otherAnimation {
    0%   {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    25%  {
        transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    50%  {
        transform: scale(0.50);
    }
    75%  {
        transform: scale(0.25);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="main"><br>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p>MyBack</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button>Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following lines from the `.remove` class in your CSS.

```
-webkit-transform-origin: right center;
-moz-transform-origin: right center;
-o-transform-origin: right center;
transform-origin: right center;
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified the `transform-origin: right center` inside the *.remove* class:

```
.remove{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;  // Remove this line
    -moz-transform-origin: right center;     // Remove this line
    -o-transform-origin: right center;       // Remove this line
    transform-origin: right center;          // Remove this line
    animation: removeAnim 0.5s ease,
    otherAnimation 0.5s ease;
}
```

You can just remove the lines because `center center` is the default behavior